# Adding a column to a python pandas data frame based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some pandas data frame, and I would like to add a column that is the difference of a column, based on the value of a third column. Here is a toy example:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

     d = {'one' : pd.Series(range(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    'two' : pd.Series(range(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    df['three'] = [2,2,3,3]


    four = []
    for i in set(df['three']):
        for j in range(len(df) -1):
            four.append(df[df['three'] == i]['two'][j + 1] - df[df['three']==i]['two'][j])
    four.append(0)

    df['four'] = four
```

The final column should be [1, 1, 1, Nan], since that is the difference between each of the rows in the 'two' column

This makes more sense in the context of my original code -- my data frame is organized by some IDs, and then by time, and when I take the subset of the data frame by IDs, I'm left with the time series evolution of the variables for each individual ID. However, I keep on either receiving a key error, or attempting to edit a copy of the original data frame. What is the right way to go about this?

Comment: what output do you want? currently it's just a list...

Comment: if you actually want another column, could you show what the final column should look like for at least one row?

Comment: Yup, I went ahead and edited my answer, it is hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `df[df['three'] == i]` with a `groupby` on column three. And perhaps replace `['two'][j + 1] - ['two'][j]` with `df['two'].shift(-1) - df['two']`.

I think that would be identical to what you are doing now within the nested loop. It depends a bit on what format you want as a result on how you would implement this. One way would be:

```
df.groupby('three').apply(lambda grp: pd.Series(grp['two'].shift(-1) - grp['two']))
```

Which would result in:

```
two    a   b
three       
2      1 NaN
3      1 NaN
```

The columns names become a bit meaningless after this operation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, that's not quite what I'm trying to do -- I've edited my response so that it is hopefully clearer now. I would still like to maintain the same number of rows and columns in the original data frame after the operations.

Comment: I misunderstood apparently, can you fix your example so that it works and complies with your text. The loop in total now runs six times (outer twice and inner 3x), and you append once outside the loop. How is that going to give a list with length 4?

Comment: Yes, so that's the problem, I couldn't get an example that works. The example is the best approximation of what I think should do what I am trying to do, but ultimately, I don't know how to generate the output that I want to generate.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to get the difference between the rows of column two you use the [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method.

```
df['four'] = df.two.shift(-1) - df.two
```